# How to share cookies between multiple runs of Apify SDK crawlers

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, cheerio, apify

With [Apify](https://sdk.apify.com/), I'm trying to scrape search results from a site that requires logins:

1. Fetch the login page to get the login token (it's a hidden form field in the login form)
2. Make a request that simulates logging in
3. Run a search on the site to find out how many pages of search results
4. Crawl each page of search results

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to share the same cookies (aka session) between steps 1-4. What I'd prefer is a clean separation in my code, like this:

```js
Apify.main(async () => {
  await clearApifyCache();

  // what should this code be to enable sharing sessions
  // between each crawl step?
  const context = ?????

  const loginToken = await getLoginToken(context);  // Step 1
  await login(context, loginToken); // Step 2
  const pageCount = await getPageCount(context); // Step 3
  const results = await getJobList(context, pageCount); // Step 4

  await Promise.all([writeCsv(results), writeHtml(results)]);
});
```

I could build this more like a state machine, where there's a single [`Apify.CheerioCrawler`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/cheerio-crawler) instance and each request adds the next request(s) to the [`RequestQueue`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/request-queue). I could probably even simulate my desired code flow by making having `handlePageFunction` iterate through a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).  Which is probably what I'll try next.

But is there a simpler way that I can maintain a simpler, procedural flow using regular `async`/`await`? OK if no, I was just wondering if I was missing an obvious way to share session state across different runs of the same crawler or between different crawler instances.  FWIW, I'm only crawling ~20 pages so perf isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Apify contains a [SessionPool](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/session-pool) that is exactly for that use case. You can create a custom session pool for your code, that will share a common named Key Value store, as such:

```js
const sessionPool = await Apify.openSessionPool({
   persistStateKeyValueStoreId: 'your-named-storage',
   persistStateKey: 'sessions' // by default it's SDK_SESSION_POOL_STATE
});

sessionPool.getSession(); // gets or create a new session
sessionPool.addSession(); // explicitly adds a session
```

This allows you to create new sessions when needed, and store sessions (along with cookies and `userData`) for those sessions that were already successful and this can be reused between runs.

But this is abstracted away into CheerioCrawler, as the `useSessionPool` parameter defaults to `true`. You can configure it using `sessionPoolOptions`.

The whole process can be solved without relying on sessions, just by using labels and passing the loginToken around:

```js
const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();

await requestQueue.addRequest({
  url: 'https://example.com/login',
  method: 'POST',
  payload: 'username=value1&password=value2',
  userData: {
    label: 'LOGIN',
  }
});

new CheerioCrawler({
  requestQueue,
  handlePageFunction: async (context) => {
     const { request, response } = context;
     const { label } = request.userData;

     switch (label) { 
       case 'LOGIN': {
          const loginToken = await getLoginToken(context);  // Step 1

          // add the request for step 2, so it can keep track of where it is
          await requestQueue.addRequest({
            url: 'https://example.com/search',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              cookie: response.headers['set-cookie'], // if it uses cookies
              someTokenHeader: loginToken, // plug it somewhere. if it's a payload, use payload. if it's in the URL, add to the `url` property
            },
            userData: {
              label: 'SEARCH',
              loginToken,
            }
          });

          break;
       }
       case 'SEARCH': {
         const { loginToken } = request.userData;
         await login(context, loginToken);
         const pageCount = await getPageCount(context); // Step 3

         await requestQueue.addRequest({
           url: 'https://example.com/details',
           userData: {
              ...request.userData, // merge the previous information here
              label: 'DETAILS',
              pageCount,
           }
         });

         break;
       }
       case 'DETAILS': {
         // since it's the last step, we can push the data
         const { pageCount } = request.userData;
         const results = await getJobList(context, pageCount);
         
         await Apify.pushData(results);

         break;
       }
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: Yep, I was hoping to avoid this kind of state machine complexity where I have to make each step aware of steps before and after it. Sounds like that's not possible. Thanks for the info.

Comment: BTW, while testing this I ran into a separate issue: cookies returned by a 302 response aren't sent back to the server in the redirected-to request. https://github.com/apify/apify-js/issues/1267

Comment: it's usually done in smaller steps so if one of the steps fail, it can be retried in isolation instead of starting everything again. and to be able to scale, even if it isn't you main concern, that's usually the best approach. in a context of being a browser you could try to do all in one go, using `page.waitForNavigation` or `page.waitForResponse`, and the whole process would be retried if any of the steps fail